# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) Error in php even though i gave 1024MB size in php.ini

Tags: php, csv, web

apologies in advance if answer exist already but i cant seem to find the solution
all i want is to convert csv into array and i cant seem to get rid of error no matter how much memory i provide

```
if (($handle =fopen('price.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $array[]=$data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
echo count($array);
```

csv file is around 3MB with around 1100 lines
how do i remove this error i tried allocating memory of 1024MB even .

Comment: How are you configuring php for more memory? use the phpinfo() command to make sure you're setting it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this in PHP before your Code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

You can try whats required it's never a goof idea to modify this value in php.ini, because other PHP processes could eat up your memory.

Comment: thnx it works. im still new in coding so im just afraid raising memory limit to too high as it might cause issues later i believe.